# Creating new bootstrap row when using handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, handlebars.js

I'm using handlebars.js to create templates for a webpage. So far I have some data stored in an array in a  JS file. This is then being rendered on a HTML page. I'm using the {{#each}} to loop through the array. This all works fine and renders correctly.

I'm using Bootstrap 3 for the framework. I'd like to break out of the loop after 4 content blocks have been displayed and create a new row with another 4 content blocks and so on.

I'm just wondering what the best approach is for this.

My code so far is

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="listings-nav row"></div>
    <script id="listings-template" type="x-handlebars-template">
       {{#each this}}
            <div class="col-lg-3 listings">
                <img class="" src="{{imgURL}}">
                <span>{{genre}} / {{date}} {{#if age}} - <strong>{{age}}</strong>{{/if}}</span>
                <a href="{{url}}"><h3>{{Event}}</h3></a>
                <p>{{venue}}</p>
            </div>
        {{/each}}
    </script>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 $(function  () {



    var listingsData = [
      {

    age:45, 
    imgURL: 'http://placehold.it/300x200', 
    url: "http://www.google.com/", 
    Event:"Evening Classes for all @ Dancehouse", 
    venue:"Dancehouse, 1 Foley St, Dublin 1", 
    genre:"Dance", 
    date:"17.12.2013"
  }, 
  {
    imgURL: 'http://placehold.it/300x200', 
    url: "http://www.google.com/", 
    Event:"Dublin Divided: September 2013", 
    venue:"Hugh Lane Gallery, Charelmout House, Parnel Square North, Dublin 1", 
    genre:"Theatre", 
    date:"17.12.2013"
  }, 
  {
    imgURL: 'http://placehold.it/300x200', 
    url: "http://www.google.com/", 
    Event:"Leonora Carrington Exhibition", 
    venue:"Irish Museum of Modern Art, Kilmainham, Dublin ", 
    genre:"Art", 
    date:"17.12.2013"
  },
  {
    imgURL: 'http://placehold.it/300x200', 
    url: "http://www.google.com/", 
    Event:"Sunday Theatre ensemble", 
    venue:"The Grand Social, Wellington Quay, Dublin 2", 
    genre:"Dance", 
    date:"17.12.2013"
  }, 
  {
    imgURL: 'http://placehold.it/300x200', 
    url: "http://www.google.com/", 
    Event:"Dublin Divided: September 2013", 
    venue:"Hugh Lane Gallery, Charelmout House, Parnel Square North, Dublin 1", 
    genre:"Theatre", 
    date:"17.12.2013"
  }
  ];
   //Get the HTML from the template   in the script tag
    var theTemplateScript = $("#listings-template").html(); 

   //Compile the template
    var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile (theTemplateScript); 
    $(".listings-nav").append (theTemplate(listingsData)); 
});
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handlebars doesn't really support this, but you can do it with a simple loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < listingsData.length; i += 4) {
    $(".listings-nav").append(theTemplate(listingsData.slice(i, i + 4)));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6LvY9/1/